# render jpg byte array sequence with python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I receive a jpg sequence from network and wish to draw it on screen.

I want to use turtle to draw it but now I only know turtle accept gif as background image but not jpg.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import turtle

image = "demo.gif"
screen = turtle.Screen()

screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)

turtle.mainloop()
```

How can I draw jpg from byte array to turtle? Or any other better framework to show video sequence?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.bgpic)

Answer (score 0):

opencv can do it perfect!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

def openfile(filename):
    fd = open("test.jpg","rb")
    frame = fd.read()
    frame = np.array(bytearray(frame))    
    fd.close()
    frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, 1)
    return frame

def openfile2(filename):
    frame = cv2.imread(filename)
    return frame

frame = openfile("test.jpg")
title = "jpeg"
cv2.namedWindow(title,cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv2.imshow(title,frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```